# SaveAttachmentsToDisk VBA code not working

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
  Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
  Dim sSaveFolder As String
  sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\axt112\Desktop\downloads\"
  For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    If oAttachment = "Checkpoint Volume and Movement Times*" Then oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
  Next
End Sub
```

I'm using Outlook VBA code to save attachments with certain files on, into a specified folder. The rule runs this script, I don't see anything wrong with the rules, so I assume its the code.

It's weird because it worked fine last week, and I haven't changed anything. Do you guys see anything weird in the code?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to move `oAttachment.SaveAsFile...` right after `Then` in the same line, or insert `End if` as a new line after `oAttachment.SaveAsFile...`

Comment: It's already after the then, and I tried the End if but it doesnt work :/

Comment: `If oAttachment Like "Checkpoint Volume and Movement Times*" Then` unless your attachments have that exact name...  Should also maybe be `If oAttachment.DisplayName`

Comment: It's in the same line. Ran it again with like and doesn't work. Maybe there's a server issue or something?

Comment: Do you get any error when you run it? You can also try left function: `If Left(oAttachment, 36) = "Checkpoint Volume and Movement Times" Then`

Comment: still not working. I can't even strip the attachments without any descriptions which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare Outlook objects and strings in VBA. Most probably you expected to compare the [DisplayName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862398.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the Attachment class which returns a string representing the name, which does not need to be the actual file name, displayed below the icon representing the embedded attachment.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
  Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
  Dim sSaveFolder As String
  sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\axt112\Desktop\downloads\"
  For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    If oAttachment.DisplayName = "Checkpoint Volume and Movement Times*" Then          
       oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
    Next
End Sub
```

or use the Like function:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
  Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
  Dim sSaveFolder As String
  sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\axt112\Desktop\downloads\"
  For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    If oAttachment.DisplayName Like "Checkpoint Volume and Movement Times*" Then          
       oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
    Next
End Sub
```

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.